Mediawiki Scribunto: <div style=> renders the entire variable it is a part of nil
The wiki page in question.
The presence of <div style=> inside a Lua template's variable (content or args[1]) renders the entire variable nil.
Template and module used:

Module:BubbleBox/hex: A Lua module to sandwich content/args[1] between a preset div class and style.

Template:BubbleBox/hex: Mediawiki template that invokes the aforementioned Module.



Screenshot of expected vs. result

Expected (how it should look): The image and caption shows and centered properly.
Result: Said <div style=> makes the entire args[1] variable nil.


Classical. = in a numbered template parameter makes it technically named: {{t|a=b}} will not be treated as {{t|1=a=b}}.
You should either replace = with {{=}}:
{{BubbleBox/hex
|classes=tagInfobox
|styles=width: 350px; padding: 8px; float: right;
|{{InfoboxTitle/hex|TEST}}
<div style{{=}}"text-align: center;">
[[File:Inkipedia Logo 2022 - S3.svg]]
Insert caption here
</div>
{{{!}}
{{InfoboxProperty/hex|TEST|text 1}}
{{InfoboxProperty/hex|TEST2|text 2}}
{{InfoboxProperty/hex|TEST333333|text 3 loong}}
{{!}}}
}}

or explicitly state the argument name:
{{BubbleBox/hex
|classes=tagInfobox
|styles=width: 350px; padding: 8px; float: right;
|1={{InfoboxTitle/hex|TEST}}
<div style="text-align: center;">
[[File:Inkipedia Logo 2022 - S3.svg]]
Insert caption here
</div>
{{{!}}
{{InfoboxProperty/hex|TEST|text 1}}
{{InfoboxProperty/hex|TEST2|text 2}}
{{InfoboxProperty/hex|TEST333333|text 3 loong}}
{{!}}}
}}

